# How to prove that person is really the GOD?

Tags: gods

If a random person comes infornt of me ,and says "I created this world and I am the ultimate creator, I am the GOD".

What question I should ask the god , so that the answer from the god makes me belive 100%  that the person is actually the god or creator of us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would the Abrahamic God reveal himself to people to convince them that He is the Abrahamic God?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26813/how-would-the-abrahamic-god-reveal-himself-to-people-to-convince-them-that-he-is)

Comment: why its opnion based ? because its about religion ? if god exists or not, that might be opnion based, but, he is not asking if god exists, rather, he is asking how would someone prove he is god... this is a logical question...

Comment: If you think this question is proper ..please click here [reopen](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74449/how-to-prove-that-person-is-really-the-god?noredirect=1#)

Comment: I wouldn't say this is opinion based - I believe the question has potential answers. However it is more of a philosophical question. If it were worldbuilding you would describe a god your world has, outlining their limits and achievements, tell us of the population of this world and then ask how that god could convince those people that something or someone spoke for him. (Even then it is only potentially redeemable as worldbuilding but I think it can be on-topic). What is your motivation behind asking the question? Is it a story you're making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Does god even want to prove it?

What if this god does not want to prove it.  You are a simple single human, does this god even care whether or not you believe what it is saying is true or not?  It knows that it is a god, what does it care if you believe it is or not.

In this scenario there is no question you can ask that will achieve your desired result.

### God already has decided to prove it

If this god has decided to reveal itself to you and convince you of its deity then it really does not matter what you ask or if you ask.  It has already crafted the exact statement and will say it in the exact way that will cut to the core of your existence in such a way that you have no doubts that the one you are interacting with is god.  The statement could be as simple as "I created you", but because of how god says the line, it resonates with you in such a way that you know it is true.  Think of it like a password to your heart that only a god would know.

### Conclusion

If this individual is in fact a god you really have no control or power to force your goal onto the situation.

Comment: One minor loophole in your conclusion might be if the god decided to provide us with libertarian freewill for whatever reason.  Some people are comfortable with the idea of an omnipotent deity being unable to break our freewill because that deity chose to be unable to.

Comment: _God already has decided to prove it._ Share this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to ask a question.  If you have to ask a question, it falls into the limits of language, and those limits are fascinatingly tricky when it comes to proofs in that form.  In fact, they are so limiting that there have been many arguments made through the millennia of philosophy suggesting no such proof could ever be provided (especially not in a formal language that isn't known a-priori).

Such a creator should be able to apply a proof directly to your Self to make you believe 100%.  What you need to see to believe is very personal.  No two people will need the same two things.  At most, the question is just a prompt to make the process go smoother.  It's also not a guarantee that they are the ultimate creator, just a being powerful enough to convince you to believe.  That's actually a lower bar because you are not infallible.

Personally, my question would be "Do you like fish sticks and custard?"  That person I'd follow to the ends of the universe.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please explain if [$\mathrm{P=NP}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) and why?

Comment: The person wouldn't have to be a god to solve P vs. NP. Additionally, if there *is* a proof, it would likely be more complicated than the average person could understand.

Comment: Proving that P and NP are the same or not would be a good first step. Next step: tell us how to quantize the gravitational field, or tell us why this is not possible. Next step: tell us how to make stable wormholes. The series of steps is of course infinite, because the gap between humans and divinities is infinitely large.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that this creator is not omnipotent. He/she/zhi/they/it built the world and exist in it but cannot just do any old magic in the world without breaking it. If they can do anything, they just change your mind so you believe.

So this person wants to prove zhi is the creator? First, as a creator, they probably embedded proof in the universe at the beginning, like, "You see the moon? Connect the dots between all the solar system moons every 10,000 years... it spells my name in English. Every 1000 years, they line up for my name in a different language." Or "yeah, I wrote my life story in the DNA of catfish. Go ahead... I'll wait while you translate."

If zhi didn't plan ahead like that, zhi should be able to give you EXACT values for the 19 fundamental unitless constants that make up our universe. We have approximations for them (example: go to Wikipedia for "fine structure constant"). But if someone told us the exact values zhi used, we could test that in physics and verify the results. That would be pretty strong evidence that this person knew their own work, since deriving those values experimentally is beyond our tech (and possibly permanently beyond our tech except by guess-and-check and there are more combinations than we could ever check in the lifetime of the universe).

Comment: who is "zhi"? --cut---lalalal long enough mesaaaageee

Comment: Zhi: pronoun when gender is ambiguous. Included in my early list of pronouns at start of answer to provide context to those who may be unfamiliar. @MolbOrg

Comment: For the shake of international community use the bible pronoun or things prior 1980.

Comment: Whose bible? I put it in context and Google exists. I have several trans friends who have challenged me to avoid discriminatory pronouns recently. I'm trying it out in as many contexts as I can. Assuming male for a authority figure outside of any specific religion implicitly links maleness to power and reinforces subconscious biases that then creep into other venues.

Comment: @SRM "They" is perfectly sufficient as a neutral pronoun.

Comment: @angelpray hardly. That is a plural noun. And in too many situations, PARTICULARLY when discussing deities or other sci-fi concepts, it becomes confusing.

Comment: Ah, you do amuse me! Oh, apologies, "you" is a plural pronoun! My mistake!          I should have said "Ah, _thou_ amusith me!". Jokes aside, I don't see how in this instance replacing "zhi" with "they" would do anything to the answer aside from making it less confusing.

Comment: @angelpray The point is to use the new pronouns in appropriate contexts to fix English. And, yes, I do use y'all on a regular basis.

Comment: The way the question is phrased - ie. it actually asks about thing-that-built-the-world without mentioning any other attributes associated with deities - I believe this is the definitive answer. (Although, as a pointless technicality that comes up because we're already discussing deity-shaped fictional constructs, you could probably mention that an omniscient being could pose as such world-creator.)

Answer (score 0):

You'd ask for irrefutable proof. There wouldn't be a thing it can say that would proof his claim. It need to give you irrefutable proof. Now what that would be I don't know. I can't think of anything. At best it show can powers much beyond any human but that doesn't directly proof he is also our creator.

Really you ask what question can you ask that would give you faith to believe the claim of the other. That sounds very personal and subjective and not a good question to ask here.